fetch only one data of single document instead of all documents
I'm trying to fetch all data of documents inside the collection but unfortunately the code only fetch data of one single document.
    const Charities = ({navigation}) => {
        
        const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    
    
        {/*fetch all documents from firestore*/}
        const fetchData = async()=>{
    
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Charities"));
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
             
              console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
              setUserData(doc.data())
            });               
    }
    
        useEffect(() => {
            fetchData()
           
        },[])



 function renderBody(){
        return(
            <View  
               
                 style={{
                // paddingBottom:100,
                 marginTop:10,
                 height:300,
                 alignItems:'center',
                 justifyContent:'center'
            }}>
               
             <Text>{userData?.Name}</Text>
           
             
            
            </View>
        )
    }


}

Between the code of fetching document from the official firebase website which only retrieve the info of the one document instead of all documents. So, I want the code to fetch all data of all documents that is what I'm expected. Your help is highly appreciated.



Is the problem that only one document is being returned, or is the problem that you receive multiple documents but only one gets put into the state?

It looks like you're calling setUserData once for each document in the result set, overwriting the result of the prior call.  Is that what you want?

The problem is that only one document being returned and I want multiple documents to be returned and display as list @NicholasTower

Your query look correct for that. It will return all the documents in the collection. Perhaps there's only one document in that collection? The screenshot you showed is for a different collection, so we have no way to know. As doug mentioned, your code for setting state looks like it's overwriting state, but i'm glad you have debugged it and ruled that out.

the collection has two documents as the screenshot showing above you, I have edited, and the code only fetch one document data why? I don't know? between in the console.log the code fetch both documents  data see the new screenshot

in the console.log the code fetch both documents That is the information i was looking for. So: you are getting multiple documents, but then you only putting one of them in state. You will get quicker answers if you include these debugging details in your questions.

it is solved thanks for being helpful

You are logging each document to the console with forEach, but you are assigning a new doc.data to the same state each time. Instead, you can push each doc.data into an array and then update the state with the whole array.
const fetchData = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Charities"));
    const data = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      data.push(doc.data());
    });
    setUserData(data);
  };

//or

const fetchData = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Charities"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    setUserData(prevData => [...prevData, doc.data()]);
  });
};


Unfortunately, I got blank screen no data displays at all @0x74h51N

If you don't change your return code you can't show any data on screen. You should map your userData state like this:  userData.map((item, index) => (<Text key={index}>{item.Name}</Text>))

Awesome........ I don't know how to thank you dude.. it is working as expected
